# Passing zero or variable number of values to Click.Option

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

Suppose we have the following function, which
has an optional parameter `exclude`, which is expected
to be a list of strings:

```
@group.command()
@click.option(???)
def load(exclude = None):
    # ...
```

I want the user to be able to execute the script like so:

```
python script.py load --exclude one two three
```

or

```
python script.py load --exclude something
```

In which case, I would expect `exclude` to be
`['one', 'two', 'three']` and `['something']`, respectively.
But I want the number of values in `--exclude` to be variable, including 0. I.e. The user should be able to execute

```
python script.py load
```

In which case `exclude` should be `None` (or `[]`, does not matter).

How can I do that using click?

My only viable option so far is forcing the user to use

```
python script.py load --exclude "one two three"
```

and then calling `exclude.split()`, but something cleaner would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be supported, in the way that you want, by Click:

According to the docs [Multi Value Options](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#multi-value-options) must have the number of options provided as specified in `nargs`, so `nargs=2` requires 2 values.

additionally, [multiple options](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#multiple-options) will not negate the need to pass the option multiple times.

Your most likely solution is to pass a string and split, although I haven't used Click too deeply, so someone may have a better solution.